# How to disable pagination in ember models table

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember models table for a project to display data. I would like to get rid of the table pagination. So far I was not able to find a viable solution to accomplish this.

Does anyone has an idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see the pagination at all, you can pass in the option showComponentFooter =  false, which will hide the bottom footer.

```
{{models-table
  data=data
  columns=columns
  showComponentFooter=false
}}
```

Doing this doesn't allow the user to navigate to page 2+, which might be acceptable to you if you expect them to use filters to see any other data.

If that doesn't work, you can also specify the page size when you instantiate the component.  Either set it to a large number, or set it to the number of records you have.

```
{{models-table
  data=data
  columns=columns
  showComponentFooter=false
  pageSize=1000
}}
```